# How do I validate email in array laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation, validationrules

I am sending data request in this format to my laravel backend application

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "email" => "sam@gmail.com"
    "role_id" => 2
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "email" => "joy@gmail.com"
    "role_id" => 3
  ]
]
```

How do I validate the email and role_id in laravel

Answer (score 1):

If your validation is generated using `php artisan make:request` use the `rules` method.

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 * @return array
 */
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'array_name' => ['required', 'array'],
        'array_name.*.email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'array_name.*.role_id' => ['required', '...'],
    ];
}
```

The same validation rules can be applied within the controller `validate` method.